# Set custom shipment email template, for spesific shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, email-templates

Standard shipment emails are:

> app/locale/en_US/email/sales/shipment_new.phtml
>   app/locale/en_US/email/sales/shipment_new_guest.phtml

In case an order has been made using a specific shipping method, I would like to set a custom shipment email template.

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and rewrite `queueNewOrderEmail` method. So in your module's `config.xml`:

```
...
<global>
    ...
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <order>Your_Module_Model_Order</order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
    ...
</global>
```

Then in `app/code/[pool]/Your/Module/Model/Order.php`

```
class Your_Module_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{
    /**
     * Queue email with new order data
     *
     * @param bool $forceMode if true then email will be sent regardless of the fact that it was already sent previously
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
    {
        ...
        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }

        // Add your logic here. You should update $templateId
        $shippingMethod = $this->getShippingMethod(true);
        if ($shippingMethod->getCarrierCode() == 'something')
        {
            $templateId = 'id';
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Personally, I don't like this approach. Overriding the whole `order` model just to change an email template is not something you usually want to do. But it should get you on the right track.